# st_intersects in where clause returning inconsistent data

Tags: postgis

In our application we are performing a bounding box search with incoming bounding box coordinates we are converting to a polygon. In our database we are having existing locations as point in a table in geometry column. We are framing query to get the point locations which are inside the polygon.

```
select * from table1 where
ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID('POLYGON((5.372134 85.0868074,5.372134 36.556537,5.9306269 36.556537,5.9306269 85.0868074,5.372134 85.0868074))'::geometry,
4326)::geography,table1.geom);
```

when point coordinate which lies outside the polygon are present in the column the where clause returns expected result for first row but after that it is returning inconsistent results

Comment: What is the type of `table1.geom` ? Which version of Postgres / PostGIS ?

Comment: you are using geography, so great circles connect points instead of straight lines. Since your polygon spans like 50 degrees, the arc curvature will be quiet important

Comment: see this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/367474/84870)

Comment: @JGH I observed a behaviour when I try to run the below query it returns false but the same co-ordinate present in the table1.geom returns true in the query mentioned in the question select 
ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID('POLYGON((5.372134 85.0868074,5.372134 36.556537,5.9306269 36.556537,5.9306269 85.0868074,5.372134 85.0868074))'::geometry,
4326)::geography,ST_SetSRID('POINT(90.4083946672047 23.7897930523202)'::geometry ,4326)::geography);

Comment: @J.Monticolo we are using Aurora Postgres 13.4 and Postgis 3.1.4

Comment: Try this function and tell us if it works : https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Covers.html

Comment: Are you sure table1.geom is a proper geography and was not transformed at some point ? Also, maybe try to run an `ANALYZE table1` just to be sure to have clean indexes and metadata.