# lat/long lookup in GeoJSON regions provided by US state governments

Tags: postgis, mysql-spatial

I have polygon data (usually GeoJSON format) for various city and county boundaries from several US state governments.  Example: [New Mexico tax districts](https://rgis.unm.edu/rgis6/dataset.html?uuid=eaf49b20-8234-4ec8-9e1a-247e98237f90).

Given a lat/long coordinate, I need to figure out which city/county it falls under.  I'm planning on using MySQL 8 or Postgres 13 to store the regions.

Questions:

1. What are the pros/cons of using `geography` vs `geometry` for this?

   - MySQL only supports `geometry`.
   - For PostGIS, this FAQ entry was a helpful start: [link](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_FAQ.html#idm33821)

     - Few functions handle `geography`, but `ST_Intersection` does, and I think it does everything I need.
     - Apparently `geography` calculations can be much slower.
2. I see mentions of things like "spatial reference systems" and "WGS84".

   - Is GeoJSON data tied to a specific spatial reference system?
   - Do I have to perform any transformations on GeoJSON data or the lat/long coordinates before checking for containment?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: One question per *Question* only - that's the rules. You are touching a few major core concepts of geospatial data analysis, as well as geometric predicates, different system specifics and OGC standards here...I am aware all these come up when starting the conceptuation, but an answer to each of these topics *individually* would be rather intense. Start out with one detailed issue, and work on to the next (and ask individual *Questions* after searching the board for answers first - many of your questions have plenty of answers already).

Comment: Geography uses great circles and not straight lines, which can be an issue if your polygons have few vertices far away from each other. See this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324171/points-within-polygons-in-different-projections/324180#324180) for an illustration.

Answer (score 1):

You ask more than one question, but for GeoJSON

> Is GeoJSON data tied to a specific spatial reference system?

Yes, the GeoJSON format is defined by the [RFC7946 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946)

> Coordinate Reference System
>
> The coordinate reference system for all GeoJSON coordinates is a
> geographic coordinate reference system, using the World Geodetic
> System 1984 (WGS 84) [WGS84] datum, with longitude and latitude units
> of decimal degrees.  This is equivalent to the coordinate reference
> system identified by the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) URN
> urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84.  An OPTIONAL third-position element SHALL
> be the height in meters above or below the WGS 84 reference
> ellipsoid.  In the absence of elevation values, applications
> sensitive to height or depth SHOULD interpret positions as being at
> local ground or sea level.
>
> Note: the use of alternative coordinate reference systems was
> specified in [GJ2008], but it has been removed from this version of
> the specification because the use of different coordinate reference
> systems -- especially in the manner specified in [GJ2008] -- has
> proven to have interoperability issues.  In general, GeoJSON
> processing software is not expected to have access to coordinate
> reference system databases or to have network access to coordinate
> reference system transformation parameters.  However, where all
> involved parties have a prior arrangement, alternative coordinate
> reference systems can be used without risk of data being
> misinterpreted.

The following URLS provide the full definitions

http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84 (for coordinates without height)

http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/0/CRS84h (for coordinates with height)

Comment: Pedantic note: it is defined in the standard alright, and *should* be honed, but nothing stops you from using whatever you want in GeoJSON - many, if not most consuming frameworks do no validation for you. Just so that OP is aware of this pitfall.

Comment: @geozelot, yes as long as all parties are aware you can do it, as stated in the final sentence of the second paragraph.